# Is there any way/tools to change a build file into solution file in asp.net, if solution file is misplaced and there is no backup of solution file?

Tags: asp.net, build, webforms, solution

I have a build file of one of my applications deployed on my server.

I lost my laptop, and unfortunately, I had no backup of my solution file.

Now I want to make changes in my application, but I have no solution file of that application.

The application was made on ASP.net web forms.

Comment: When you say "build file", do you mean a `.csproj` file? In that case, I'd create a new (empty) solution and add the project to it. In a new directory of course.

Comment: I meant the published files which includes bin folder and the .dll files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need a Decompiler like [DotPeek](https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/) which enables you to decompile the dll's and save them as a code projects (c# or vb.net).